# Can't align icon and text baseline

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to align an icon and a text with CrossAxisAlignment.baseline but I can't get it right.

**What I want**

[image]

**What I get**

[image]

This is my code:

```
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
  textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
  children: [
    Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined),
    Text(
      "Cloud",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
    )
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the cross axis alignment to end

```
Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined, size: 20),
                  SizedBox(width: 5),
                  Text(
                    "Cloud",
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Result:-

[image]

Comment: I need to have both aligned to the bottom so i tried the second snippet and it doesn't solve the problem, it seems that the text is aligned correctly with the icon but the icon has a 1:1 aspect ratio resulting in a kind of padding on the bottom of it that i can't remove

Comment: Have you copied the same code as provided in my snippet as i am obtaining the right image as shown in the my update answer.

Comment: I did, but te problem is that it works only with those sizes, if i wanna tweak for instance the size of the text it's again not aligned

Answer (score -1):

You can used ListTile insted of Row

Using **ListTile**

```
 ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined),
        title: Text(
          "Cloud",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
        ),
      ),
```

Using **Row**:

```
     Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: const [
            Icon(Icons.cloud_outlined),
            SizedBox(width: 10),
            Text(
              "Cloud",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: This answer doesn't work for Cupertino as a root widget. ListTile widgets require a Material widget ancestor. This makes the answer very limiting for many cases.

Comment: @KonstantinKozirev I have update my answer using Row widget try this one hope its help to you.