# Flutter: How to vertical align Icon and Text to baseline within a Row?

Tags: flutter

I have an Icon, big text, and small text in a row, all with various height. I want to vertical align them to one baseline

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
          children: const [
            Icon(
              Icons.star_rounded,
              color: Colors.yellow,
              size: 36,
            ),
            Text(
              "4.5",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 35),
            ),
            Text(
              "/5.0",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 16),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I want the star **icon to stick to the baseline (blueline)**

[image]

I've tried the solution in this [Can't align icon and text baseline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68270808/cant-align-icon-and-text-baseline) but it doesn't work for my case

Comment: can you share what's it's look like after apply what this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68270808/cant-align-icon-and-text-baseline is saying

Comment: Because this is what I've tried ```Row(
              textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: const [
                ...
              ],
            ),```
and it's working for me

Comment: @RohanJariwala https://imgur.com/dLn1F42. Only the icon & /5.0 text align at the bottom. The big text (4.5) is lifted from the "ground"

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, hope snippet give you the expected output
Just Wrap **Row** with **Column**.& set Row CrossAxisAlignment ==                 `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,`

[image]

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            children: const [
              Icon(
                Icons.star_rounded,
                color: Colors.yellow,
                size: 36,
              ),
              Text(
                "4.5",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 35),
              ),
              Text(
                "/5.0",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54, fontSize: 16),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/ekWTG9b I tried it, but the star icon still appears floating up from the baseline.

Comment: Icon size 36 means it takes width and height from all around area 36 and icon will be in the center of the specific area.  you can try another way making Row ==          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, Answer edited. Result will be as you expected. I have checked.

Comment: In your example, the "4.5" is lifted, not as my expected solution where all star icon, "4.5" text, and "5.0" text "touching" the same baseline

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `textBaseline` property to the `Text` as well. So your row becomes:

```
                    Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                        textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            ...
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Your text",
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
                              ...
                            ),
                          ),
                          ],)
```